# Printing in python the result vertical instead of one line

Tags: python, ldap-query

when i run my python script to query a user, it prints all the results in one line(in the interpreter.)

the block of code in my python script is:

```
baseDN = "DC=top,DC=domain,DC=com"
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
retrieveAttributes = ["name"]
searchFilter = "cn=*abc*"

try:
    ldap_result_id = l.search(baseDN, searchScope, searchFilter, 
retrieveAttributes)
    result_set = []
    while 1:
        result_type, result_data = l.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
        if (result_data == []):
            break
        else:
            if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
                result_set.append(result_data)
    print result_set
except ldap.LDAPError, e:
    print e
```

the result of the above is similar to this horizontally:

```
[[('CN=John Doe ,OU=SalesOffices,DC=top,DC=domain,DC=com', {'name': ['John Doe']})], [('CN=Mary Jane,OU=SalesOffices,DC=top,DC=domain,DC=com', {'name': ['Mary Jane']})],
```

I would like it to print like this vertically:

```
[[('CN=John Doe ,OU=SalesOffices,DC=top,DC=domain,DC=com', {'name': ['John Doe']})],
[('CN=Mary Jane,OU=SalesOffices,DC=top,DC=domain,DC=com', {'name': ['Mary Jane']})],
```

Thanks!

Comment: Checkout the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pprint.html?highlight=pprint#module-pprint) module, e.g. `from pprint import pprint; pprint(result_set, width=120)`

Comment: Thanks, so how should my above script look to print as a vertical list? I'm liking this pprint module(I'm new to coding). Also- import pprint should be at beginning on python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `print result_set`, use:

```
for x in result_set:
    print x
```

Comment: Should I replace my print result_set with that block of code? What would x be?

Comment: @Xtos `x` in this case is literally every list in `result_set`, thus, it's pretty much what you want to do. Yeah, you just need to replace your `print result_set` statement.

Comment: This worked well thus far, it did not multiply the results. It has printed each attribute from AD attributes once only and not multiple times

Comment: If it worked, please upvote and accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

In python 3 or with `from __future__ import print_function` you can use the `sep` keyword and the star expression:

```
print(*result_set, sep='\n')
```

This will unpack the elements of `result_set` as single arguments to print and put a newline in between.

On a side note, you probably shouldn't  call a python list object `result_set`, as set is another builtin collection type.

Complete example (add your ldap server and basedn):

```
# __future__ imports have to be the very first imports
from __future__ import print_function
import ldap

host = 'ldap://...'
baseDN = '...'
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
retrieveAttributes = ['mail']
searchFilter = 'uid=*'

l = ldap.initialize(host)
l.simple_bind()

try:
    ldap_result_id = l.search(
        baseDN, searchScope, searchFilter, retrieveAttributes
    )
    ldap_results = []

    # use a bool, be explicit!
    while True:
        result_type, result_data = l.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
        if not result_data:
            break
        else:
            if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
                ldap_results.append(result_data)

    print(*ldap_results, sep='\n')
except ldap.LDAPError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Can I rename to anything I want? How should my code look incorporating sep and star expression? Thanks so much!

Comment: Pretty much everything you want. I would probably choose something like `ldap_results`.

Comment: Thanks, i tried this and got:
    print(*result_set, sep='\n')
          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Did you add `from __future__ import print_function` as very first line?

Comment: after adding `from __future__ import print_function` it worked but it gave me results in duplicate and triplets:
`[('CN=Christopher Mason,OU=Graveyard,OU=SalesOffices,DC=top,DC=domain,DC=com', {'name': ['Christopher Mason']})]`

`[('CN=Christopher Mason,OU=Graveyard,OU=SalesOffices,DC=top,DC=domain,DC=com', {'name': ['Christopher Mason']})]`

like the above, there should be 30 entries only, but it outputs approx 200 because it duplicates the outputs(even triplicates).

Answer (score 1):

Using the `pprint` module keeps all the list brackets:

```
from pprint import pprint

baseDN = "DC=top,DC=domain,DC=com"
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
... 
    pprint(result_set, width=120)
```

Output:

```
[[('CN=John Doe ,OU=SalesOffices,DC=top,DC=domain,DC=com', {'name': ['John Doe']})],
 [('CN=Mary Jane,OU=SalesOffices,DC=top,DC=domain,DC=com', {'name': ['Mary Jane']})]]
```

By default `pprint` tries to pretty print to 80 columns:

```
    pprint(result_set)
```

Output:

```
[[('CN=John Doe ,OU=SalesOffices,DC=top,DC=domain,DC=com',
   {'name': ['John Doe']})],
 [('CN=Mary Jane,OU=SalesOffices,DC=top,DC=domain,DC=com',
   {'name': ['Mary Jane']})]]
```

Comment: just as with maxnoe's solution the results it outputs in each line are multiplied by 2 and 3 times. do you know why?

Comment: It must be returning multiple values from the `ldap` query.